# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getBlockHeight is not defined

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, blockchain, leveldb

I have defined `getBlockHeight()` method within the `simpleChain.js`. I am using levelDb library for data persistence using another `levelDb.js` and exporting all the modules. Please excuse my innocence here, I am working with Javascript & Promises for the 1st time.

This is the `simpleChain.js`

```
    class Blockchain {
      constructor(){
        //Get block height from levelDB
         this.getBlockHeight().then(height => {
          //Check if block height is 0
          console.log('Height of Blockchain: ' + height);
          if (height === 0) {
            //Create the Genesis Block - The first block in the blockchain
            this.addBlock(
              new Block('First block in the chain - Genesis block')
            ).then(() => console.log('Genesis Block created!'))
          }
        });
      };

// Get block height
  async getBlockHeight(){
    //Return block height from levelDB
    let blockHeight  = await levelDB.getLevelBlockHeight();
    return blockHeight;
  };
```

This the code for `levelDb.js` which has exported methods

```
//Getting blockchain height from levelDB
    getLevelBlockHeight : () => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let height = 0;
        db.createReadStream()
          .on('data', function (data){
              height++;
          })
          .on('error', function (error){
              reject(error);
          })
          .on('close', function (){
            resolve(height);
          });
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Promise Error')
      });
    },
```

Here is the Error:

> (node:5896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError:
>   getBlockHeight is not defined
>       at Blockchain.addBlock (repl:38:145)
>       at Blockchain.getBlockHeight.then.height (repl:29:81)
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: if you're going to use catch like that in `getLevelBlockHeight` - you may as well be doing `resolve(undefined)` instead of `reject(error)` :p are you sure the error is exactly what you've said in the title?

Comment: @Bravo okay I understood but don't understand the code structure for javascript. :P

Comment: don't worry about the first thing I said (yet) ... can you confirm the exact error

Comment: @Bravo I have added the error log above.

Comment: I gather the code in the question isn't the exact code that produces that error - considering the values in the error trace